# /bin/jq: Argument list too long

Tags: json, jenkins, jq

I'm using groovy script and write this line
Version_List=$(`jq -r  '.items[] .version' "${projectContent}"`)

the ${projectContent} is another variable which is result of curl command
when i run the pipeline this is the error /bin/jq: Argument list too long

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq -Rs . <<< "${projectContent}"` to convert the variable content into a JSON string (you may even use `curl` directly, like so: `curl … | jq -Rs`), then import that string into a jq variable using `--slurpfile` with [Process Substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
jq --slurpfile projectContent <(
  jq -Rs . <<< "${projectContent}"
) '...' # your jq code here using variable $projectContent
```

Don't forget to also add either `-n` or an input file.

Comment: sh """
Version_List=\$(  jq --slurpfile projectContent <  (jq -Rs . <<< "${projectContent}") )
"""
i wrote this in this way but it give me another error "  syntax error near unexpected token `(' "

Comment: @user16991581 Process Substitution syntax is `<(` without a space in between.

Comment: unfortunately the same error even if i take your lines copy and paste

Comment: @user16991581 Not all shells support process substitution. Which shell are you running that command in?

Comment: /bin/bash shell , i don't think the problem is in the shell

Comment: @user16991581 Try `jq -n --slurpfile projectContent <(jq -Rs . <<< "${SHELL}") '{$projectContent}'` (and nothing else) in your terminal, as a proof of concept. It should output `{"projectContent": ["/bin/bash\n"]}` (with some pretty printing).

Comment: again same error , is there any another way to skip that error ?

Comment: can i make something like this
jq -Rs . <<< "${projectContent}" | jq .items[].version 
but the command gives me Cannot index string with string "items"

Comment: First, quote your jq code (`jq '.items[].version'`) in order to avoid conflicts with bash. Second, `--slurpfile` generates an array, and `.items` expects an object. Please describe the content of `${projectContent}`, otherwise I can't tell, whether there are other issues with `.items[].version` or not

Comment: {
  "items" : [ {
    "version" : "",
.........
}] , that's is content ,how can i write the full command ?!

Comment: @user16991581 Try `.[0].items[0].version` (this includes accessing the array generated by `--slurpfile`)

Comment: this gives Cannot index string with number

Comment: this is a sample from the output afrer slurpfile
{\n  items : [ {\n    version: .........